# Splitting a binary bit stream in N equal size using Tcl

Tags: shell, scripting, tcl, tk-toolkit

I have a number say, 10101100100011101010111010. And I want to split it in N equal sized chunks,  let's say I want an output as:
1010 1100 1000 1110 1010 1110 10
I want it to be done using Tcl . Any ideas?

I was using for loop and I was able to split the first chunk that is in Output I was able to get 1010 but not the rest chunks.

Comment: the example you give does not show equal sized chunks

Answer (score 2):

I don't speak tcl but a few manpage lookups gave me:

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh

proc str2chunksize { s cs } {
    set len [ string length $s ]

    for {set i 0; set j -1} {$i < $len} {incr i $cs} {
        incr j $cs
        lappend resultList [ string range $s $i $j ]
    }
    return $resultList
}

proc str2numchunks { s nc } {
    set len [ string length $s ]
    set cs [ expr {1 + ($len / $nc)} ]
    set excess [ expr {$len % $nc} ]

    for {set n 0; set i 0; set j -1} {$n < $nc} {incr n} {
        if {$n == $excess} {incr cs -1}
        incr j $cs
        lappend resultList [ string range $s $i $j ]
        incr i $cs
    }
    return $resultList
}


set chunks [ str2chunksize "10101100100011101010111010" 4 ]
puts [ join $chunks " " ]

set chunks [ str2chunksize "10101100100011101010111010" 7 ]
puts [ join $chunks " " ]



set chunks [ str2numchunks "10101100100011101010111010" 4 ]
puts [ join $chunks " " ]

set chunks [ str2numchunks "10101100100011101010111010" 7 ]
puts [ join $chunks " " ]

set chunks [ str2numchunks "10101100100011101010111010" 17 ]
puts [ join $chunks " " ]

set chunks [ str2numchunks "10101100100011101010111010" 30 ]
puts [ join $chunks ":" ]
```

output:

```
1010 1100 1000 1110 1010 1110 10
1010110 0100011 1010101 11010
1010110 0100011 101010 111010
1010 1100 1000 1110 1010 111 010
10 10 11 00 10 00 11 10 10 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0
1:0:1:0:1:1:0:0:1:0:0:0:1:1:1:0:1:0:1:0:1:1:1:0:1:0::::
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using [`regexp`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.html)?

```
 regexp -all -inline -- {.{1,4}} 10101100100011101010111010
```

You would have to provide for different [quantifier bounds `{m, n}`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.html#M12), with `m = 1`, and `n = N`.